# Where are docker keycloak extensions logs

Tags: docker, logging

I am trying out this extension on keycloak docker image: https://github.com/dasniko/keycloak-session-restrictor

This is the dockerfile for reference:

```
FROM jboss/keycloak:11.0.3

COPY extensions/keycloak-session-restrictor/target/keycloak-session-restrictor-1.0.0.jar /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments/

HEALTHCHECK --interval=30s --timeout=1s --retries=3 CMD curl -k --fail http://localhost:8080/auth/ || exit 1

CMD ["-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.scripts=enabled", "-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

In the `SessionRestrictorEventListenerProvider` class, I added `import org.jboss.logging.Logger` to add the following line of code for debugging:

```
logger.info("This event sessionId = " + event.getSessionId() + ", existing sessions: " + userSession.getId());
```

Now when i see the container console, it does not appear to have this log. Do I need to setup a log4j2 implementation for the JBoss logging?